# Django Oscar Template override not working

Tags: django-oscar

I am facing problem with django oscar template overriding. I am using Oscar 2.0.3 and Django 2.2.7

I am using method-1 mentioned in the docs. My project structure looks like

```
myproject
   cache
   catalogue (I have overridden this app)
   categories 
   images
   templates
      base.html
   myproject
   manage.py
```

I have edited my `TEMPLATES` as

```
import os
location = lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..', x)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [location('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and I am making changes in `base.html` but they are not replicated at `127.0.0.1:8000/catalogue/` (`127.0.0.1:8000` redirects to this url)

Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the behavior in this video youtube.com/watch?v=iFXOx7FOC9k&t=329s . When I paste the `base.html` from `django-oscar` in my own `base.html` , it does not show anything. As if it is rendering an empty html. In contrast, the steps followed in the video reproduce the landing page.

Comment: Have you checked what `location('templates')` resolves to? I think you'll find it doesn't point to the directory where you have put your templates. You can check by printing that value from the settings file.

Comment: Yeah I did. It does point to the templates folder that I am using for my local project. I could render the `base.html` but I had to do it explicitly ( by writing a `view` and editing `urls.py` to redirect to that view. I wasn't able to reproduce he behavior in the video that I have attached. @solarissmoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is for an old version of Oscar (1.6).

In Oscar 2.0 the template structure has changed. Specifically `base.html` is now at [`oscar/base.html`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/templates/oscar/base.html). This means that to override it you have to create a file at `templates/oscar/base.html` instead of `templates/base.html`.

The same applies for all other Oscar templates.

Comment: Yeah! That was the issue!! I had messed up the directory structure. Thanks a lot for the help! And an awesome project! 
@solarissmoke